# What is the difference between defaultdict and get_dummies when Encoding categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, defaultdict

Usually in python, we use get_dummies to encode categorical values, but I found the below code:

```
LABEL_ENCODERS = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)
df_new=df.apply(lambda x:LABEL_ENCODERS[x.name].fit_transform(x) \
       if x.dtype=='O' else x)
```

It is use default dict to try to encode, just wondering compared with get_dummies, any disadvantage of using defaultdict?

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately. Python is not numpy or pandas or whatever this is.

Comment: surely not _all_ of the above libraries are relevant to the question!?

Comment: I assume `get_dummies` is [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and `LabelEncoder` is [`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).  Is that correct?

Comment: Just from looking at the docs and source for `get_dummies`, it's evidently a complex `pandas` specific operation.  `defaultdict` is a basic Python extension to `dict`, but the real work is being done by the `LabelEncoder` class.  `defaultdict` is just a way of collecting the results in a dictionary.  You have understand the whole `apply` expression, but not just one piece.